# Using the binomial theorem to prove an identity

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Prove that :-

$C^{n}_0 + 3C^{n}_1 + 5C^{n}_2 +...+(2n+1)C^{n}_n = (n+1)\times 2^n$

My turn:-

We know that

$2^n = C^{n}_0 + C^{n}_1 + C^{n}_2 + ... +C^{n}_n$

Then

$(n+1)2^n = (n+1)C^{n}_0 + (n+1) C^{n}_1 + (n+1) C^{n}_2 + ... + (n+1) C^{n}_n$

I could not go on any more !

Comment: Can you clarify what the LHS is? How do the indices change? Did you really want $ 5 C^n _3$? Or should it be $ 5 C^n _2 $?

Comment: Personally I thought it was very clear that $5C^{n}_2$ is intended, and have edited the post as such.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2439878/binomial-theorem-and-nn12n-2-sum-i-1ni2-binomni/2439964?r=SearchResults#2439964

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} x^k~~~(1)$$
Take the derivative with respect to $x$ and multiply by $x$ on both sides
$$nx(1+x)^{n-1} = \sum_{k=1}^n k {n \choose k}x ^k~~~(2)$$
putting $x=1$ in (1) and (2), we get
$$2^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k},~~ n2^{n-1}= \sum_{k=0}^{n} k{n \choose k}~~~~(3)$$
Then use (3), to get the required sum mentioned in the top line of the question.
$$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n} (2k+1) {n \choose k}= 2 n 2^{n-1}+2^n=2^{n}(n+1).$$

Answer (score 2):

Recall the symmetric identity:

$$\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}$$

This means that, for example, you can swap any $\binom{n}{0}$ with an $\binom{n}{n}$. If we have $1$ of $\binom{n}{0}$ and $2n+1$ of $\binom{n}{n}$, we get $2n+2$ of these numbers total, which is the same as having $n+1$ of each.

Notice that $n+1$ is the coefficient in the middle, so for any $\binom{n}{k}$ and $\binom{n}{n-k}$ pair, the sum of the two coefficients is $2n+2$, so you can redistribute them so each has $n+1$.

$$
\begin{align}
(n+1)2^n &= 1\binom{n}{0} + 3\binom{n}{1} + 5\binom{n}{2} + 7\binom{n}{3} + \cdots + (2n+1)\binom{n}{n} \\
(n+1)2^n &= \left(1\binom{n}{0} + (2n+1)\binom{n}{n}\right) + \left(3\binom{n}{1} + (2n-1)\binom{n}{n-1}\right) + \left(5\binom{n}{2} + (2n-3)\binom{n}{n-2}\right) + \cdots \\
(n+1)2^n &= \left((n+1)\binom{n}{0} + (n+1)\binom{n}{n}\right) + \left((n+1)\binom{n}{1} + (n+1)\binom{n}{n-1}\right) + \left((n+1)\binom{n}{2} + (n+1)\binom{n}{n-2}\right) + \cdots \\
(n+1)2^n &= \left(n+1\right)\left(\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + \binom{n}{2} + \binom{n}{3} + \cdots + \binom{n}{n} \right) \\
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Combinatorial Proof:

If there are $n+1$ balls numbered from $1$ to $n+1$, then how many ways are there to paint $1$ ball black and the rest either blue or red.

There are $n+1$ to paint the black ball, then $2^n$ ways to paint red and blue balls. Therefore the total ways are
$$(n+1)\cdot 2^n$$

Another way to count would be to select the black ball first, there are $n+1$ ways to do this. Then there can be $R$ red balls such that $0\leq R\leq n$ and $n-R$ blue balls.Therefore the total ways are
$$(n+1)\cdot \sum_{R=0}^n \binom{n}{R}$$

Notice that the terms on the LHS can be arranged as the sum above by using $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$

Since both ways count the same thing, both expressions are equal.

Comment: I don't find this to be a very satisfying combinatorial proof, because the part that is proven combinatorially is the fact that $2^n = \sum \binom{n}{k}$. The asker seems to already understand that particular identity, but the last step involving the symmetric identity was done algebraically, not combinatorially.